# How to combine list of DocumentNode with named operations into a single DocumentNode with respective named operations in graphql?

Tags: python, graphql, apollo, gql

I am working on application that has to query graphql to fetch data, but when i combine list of DocumentNodes into single DocumentNode using `concat_ast` provided by graphql, I m receving the following error `graphql.error.graphql_error.GraphQLError: This anonymous operation must be the only defined operation`

I know the reason why this is happening, here is the example of what is happening when i combine the querys, the concat function is adding extra braces around each named operation, which is a incorrect graphql query syntax

Combined query

```
{
  table1: fetchTable1(
    id: [5, 45]
    perPage: 5
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    data {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

{
  table2: fetchTable2(table1_id: [5, 45], perPage: 5, currentPage: 1) {
    data {
      id
      customer
    }
  }
}
```

Individual Query, table2 is its named operation

```
{
  table2: fetchTable2(table1_id: [5, 45], perPage: 5, currentPage: 1) {
    data {
      id
      customer
    }
  }
}
```

But i need the combined result to be in the following format, so that all operations will be named, I have also tried this query in apollo graphql UI, and it works, but i could not generate one using concat in python, is there any other ways i could comibne multiple `DocumentNode`s without affecting the existing named operations.

```
{
  table1: fetchTable1(
    id: [5, 45]
    perPage: 5
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    data {
      id
      name
    }
  }

  table2: fetchTable2(table1_id: [5, 45], perPage: 5, currentPage: 1) {
    data {
      id
      customer
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried using `concat_ast` function provided by graphql, I also have a workaround in place which is to not create DocumentNodes per each table before and combinne all the tables `dict` at the end and craete a single DocumentNode, but it would be better to let graphql combine DocumentNodes into one or if any other better solutions than mine as i might need to fetch individual tables in other parts of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using [graphql-query](https://denisart.github.io/graphql-query/) package for combine GraphQL queries in python.

Code

```py
from graphql_query import Argument, Field, Operation, Query

fetchTable1 = Query(
    name="fetchTable1",
    alias="table1",
    arguments=[
        Argument(name="id", value=[5, 45]),
        Argument(name="perPage", value=5),
        Argument(name="currentPage", value=1),
    ],
    fields=[Field(name="data", fields=["id", "name"])]
)

fetchTable2 = Query(
    name="fetchTable2",
    alias="table2",
    arguments=[
        Argument(name="table1_id", value=[5, 45]),
        Argument(name="perPage", value=5),
        Argument(name="currentPage", value=1),
    ],
    fields=[Field(name="data", fields=["id", "customer"])]
)

operation = Operation(
    type="query",
    queries=[fetchTable1, fetchTable2],
)

print(operation.render())
```

The result is

```
query {
  table1: fetchTable1(
    id: [5, 45]
    perPage: 5
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    data {
      id
      name
    }
  }

  table2: fetchTable2(
    table1_id: [5, 45]
    perPage: 5
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    data {
      id
      customer
    }
  }
}
```

And creating `DocumentNode`:

```py
query = gql(operation.render())
```

Comment: Can i use gql queries with `Operation`, or i have to build the query using `graphql_query`?

Comment: you need rendering with `Operation.render()`. `gql` has its own DSL https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/dsl_module.html